# Pluging a bluetooth dongle into Kali Linux in VirtualBox

Tags: kali-linux, bluetooth

so I wanted to turn on bluetooth in kali linux, and it gave me a message saying "plug in a bluetooth dongle", and I searched for some bluetooth usb dongles, and I saw the Asus bt400 usb dongle, and I decided to order it, when it arrived, I added it to Kali's virtualbox settings, and when I turned Kali on, it kept asking for the dongle, how do I make the dongle work so I can turn on bluetooth in Kali?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the [extension pack](https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/) of VirtualBox for it to detect USB in the guest.

Then you have to add your user to vboxusers:

```
$ sudo usermod -G vboxusers -a your_user
```

For it to take effect you have to logout and login again.